# USB 5v single to +- 2.5v dual rail

Tags: power-supply, usb

Is there a better way of just using a voltage divider to split a single 5v rail into 2.5v and -2.5v? I'll be using USB for powering the circuit

Comment: This can be the best way if the current taken from the pseudo mid rail is small.

Comment: Need to know what the circuit is. You need to make sure that the ground of the USB and ground of your circuit are not in any way connected - because your 2.5V supply is becoming the new ground for the circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The +/-2.5V suggests you are doing analog or mixed-signal processing of some kind.

As well as using a voltage divider, which works okay in some situations, you can use an active rail-splitter IC to produce a low impedance virtual ground without drawing the high current a voltage divider of that output impedance would require. Using an op-amp looks similar but it can be a bit tricky because most are unstable with capacitive loads of any size.

Another way is to use a charge pump or inverting buck-boost converter to generate a -5V rail and then regulate them both down to +/-2.5V using linear regulators. That will deal with regulation and *some* noise issues.

The ground on the USB tends to be very noisy which is a severe limitation on precision applications- so an even better (albeit more expensive) way for such situations is to isolate the analog circuitry with signal isolators and a DC-DC converter to pass the power.

Answer (score 3):

If you need stable supply it's best to use a so called virtual ground.

[image]

You can add an LDO to the mix if you need it to be more stable. USB power supply varies a lot and can be quite noisy.

Comment: Isn't this the setup which is "unstable with capacitive loads of any size"?